# How to convert string to seo-url?

Tags: python, string, url, unicode, seo

I would like to convert a accented string to a seo-url ...

For instance:
"Le bébé (de 4 ans) a également un étrange "rire"" to :
"le-bebe-de-4-ans-a-egalement-un-etrange-rire"

Any solution, please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = u'Le bébé (de 4 ans) a également un étrange "rire"'
>>> r = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',a).encode('cp1256','ignore')
>>> r = unicode(re.sub('[^\w\s-]','',r).strip().lower())
>>> r = re.sub('[-\s]+','-',r)
>>> print r
le-bebe-de-4-ans-a-egalement-un-etrange-rire
```

I use cp1256 (latin 1) to handle accented characters...

Perfect ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
def _doStringSEOptiomization(objectName,pageName,lang,objectId):
"""
Prende in input il nome di un'offerta e svolge dei passi:
1- Trasforma tutte le variazioni delle vocali
   in vocali normali
2- Attraverso una serie di REGEX, elimina i caratteri non desiderati e torna 
   una stringa da inserire in un link adatto ai motori di ricerca e alle indicizzazioni
"""

try:
    import re #importo il modulo per le REGEX
    Speaker.log_debug(GREEN("core.ws_site.do_sites_offers_data_redux._doStringSEOptiomization() input: objectName=%s, pageName=%s, lang=%s, objectId=%s" % (objectName,pageName,lang,objectId)))

    #mappa dei caratteri html-entity e unicode
    vocalMap = { 'a' : ['&agrave;','&aacute;','&acirc;','&atilde;','&auml;','&aring;','&aelig;','&#224;','&#225;','&#226;','&#227;','&#228;','&#229;','&#257;','&#230;'],
                 'e' : ['&egrave;','&eacute;','&ecirc;','&euml;','&#232;','&#233;','&#234;','&#235;','&#275;'],
                 'i' : ['&igrave;','&iacute;','&icirc;','&iuml;','&#236;','&#237;','&#238;','&#239;','&#299;'],
                 'o' : ['&ograve;','&oacute;','&ocirc;','&oelig;','&otilde;','&ouml;','&#242;','&#243;','&#244;','&#339;','&#245;','&#246;','&#333;'],
                 'u' : ['&ugrave;','&uacute;','&ucirc;','&uuml;','&#249;','&#250;','&#251;','&#252;','&#363;']
                }

    objectName = objectName.lower() #trasformo la stringa di partenza in caratteri minuscoli

    for vocale, lista in vocalMap.iteritems(): #per ogni elemento della mappa avrà una chiave ed una lista
        for elemento in lista: #itero su tutti gli elementi della lista
            objectName = objectName.replace(elemento,vocale) #sostituisco nel nome dell'offerta, la vocale all' HTML-entity

    objectName = objectName.replace("/","-")

    objectName = re.sub("[^a-z0-9_\s-]","",objectName)     #######################################
    objectName = re.sub("[\s-]+"," ",objectName)           #strippo tutti i caratteri non voluti:# 
    objectName = re.sub("[\s_]","-",objectName)            #######################################

    objectName = pageName+"--"+objectName
    objectName += "-"+lang+"-"+str(objectId) #aggiungo la lingua e l'id dell'offerta

except Exception,s:
    Speaker.log_error("_doStringSEOptiomization(): Error=%s"%RED(s))

return objectName
```

You have to adapt it for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

This might (or might not) be enough:

```
import re
import unidecode

def normalized_id(title):
    title = unidecode.unidecode(title).lower()
    return re.sub('\W+', '-', title.replace("'", '')).strip('-')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Django around, you can use its defaultfilter slugify (or adapt it for your needs).

Answer (score 1):

```
[~]$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unicodedata
>>> import re
>>> def seo_string(x):
...     r = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',x).encode('ascii','ignore')
...     r = unicode(re.sub('[^\w\s-]','',x).strip().lower())
...     return re.sub('[-\s]+','-',r)
... 
>>> seo_string(u'Le bébé (de 4 ans) a également un étrange "rire"')
u'le-bb-de-4-ans-a-galement-un-trange-rire'
```

With thanks to the great [slugify](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L230) of django's built-in filters, however it won't do replacement of é with e like the solution posted by @doncallisto

Answer (score 1):

Here are the several ways to do so: [Generating Slugs](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/5/) By Armin Ronacher.